# Vertical navs in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, nav

```
<body>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <h2>Vertical Nav</h2>
  <p>Use the .flex-column class to create a vertical nav:</p>
  <ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

How do you make the navbar in bootstrap this way with more options on the right of the sidebar as in the picture?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmxSS.png)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Chances are, your question might be closed in its current state. Ideally you'd incorporate some code examples that shows your efforts and an explanation of where and why you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the Examples page from the Bootstrap site.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/examples/

[image]

**Check out the DEMO below:**

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row p-5">
    <div class="col">
      <h5>Section</h5>
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h5>Section</h5>
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h5>Section</h5>
      <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Link</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mb-2"><a href="#" class="nav-link p-0 text-muted">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I cant find that particular I was asking for that you send me. So you have to put it in a column and cant do it otherwise? In this website https://www.ikea.com/se/sv/  if you scroll at the bottom they use accordion